# how to add an entry in dot1dStaticEntry without RowStatus

Tags: snmp, bridge, mib

[RFC 4188](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4188) defines the `dot1dStaticEntry` as follows:

```
dot1dStaticEntry OBJECT-TYPE
       SYNTAX      Dot1dStaticEntry
       MAX-ACCESS  not-accessible
       STATUS      current
       DESCRIPTION
           "Filtering information configured into the bridge by
           (local or network) management specifying the set of
           ports to which frames received from a specific port and
           containing a specific destination address are allowed to
           be forwarded."
       REFERENCE
           "IEEE 802.1D-1998: clause 14.7.2"
       INDEX   { dot1dStaticAddress, dot1dStaticReceivePort }
       ::= { dot1dStaticTable 1 }



 Dot1dStaticEntry ::=
       SEQUENCE {
           dot1dStaticAddress       MacAddress,
           dot1dStaticReceivePort   Integer32,
           dot1dStaticAllowedToGoTo OCTET STRING,
           dot1dStaticStatus        INTEGER
       }
```

The columns defined for this table are all denoted `read-create`. However, there is no `RowStatus` column defined for this table.

How do I add a row in this table via SNMP, given that the table does not have a `RowStatus` column?

Comment: Please pay attention to `INDEX   { dot1dStaticAddress, dot1dStaticReceivePort }`.

Comment: I noticed the index is also read-create. From my past knowledge, the table index is not-accessible and there is a rowstatus used for creating table entries. Could you explain more on how the read-create index is used to create table entries? Or any document with that information is appreciated.

Comment: The following is from rfc2578.  For newly-defined conceptual rows which allow the creation of new
   object instances and/or the deletion of existing object instances,
   there should be one columnar object with a SYNTAX clause value of
   RowStatus (a textual convention defined in [3]) and a MAX-ACCESS
   clause value of read-create.  By convention, this is termed the
   status column for the conceptual row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah just off the top of my head that looks totally broken to me, unless there's some extension I'm not aware of.

But it *looks* like `dot1dStaticStatus` is a sort of non-standard RowStatus.

If you want to use this feature I think you'll have to ask the vendor for the equipment you're using that implements the MIB, to clarify.